# sort array or json on basis of a number/object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I am facing an issue with sorting in JSON.I have a list which can reorder and the reordering can be saved so next time whenever user will come he/she can see the reordered list the way he arranged. The image is below.[image: First time reodering] 
Now it get save in object the order and when he retrieve it back the JSON is coming in this way.[image],you can see object ResourceSortedOrder is the order which telling that on which position item will be present it will come for the checked item only the rest will have null.Now on the basis of it I am sorting the array/JSON the javascript is below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
                  if (lst[i].ResourceSortedOrder != null) {
                   var temp = lst[i];
                  lst.splice(i, 1);
                  lst.splice(temp.ResourceSortedOrder, 0, temp);
                  lst.join();
                }


            }
```

It is getting sorted but the first element which has to place at 5th position is getting placed at the 4th position because of the data above it 100srvc resources is below it in JSON. So I am getting a result like below image.
[image: The Resulted One]
Instead of my initial image.Please help

the JSON in string:

```
"[{"__type":"BusinessLayer.DTOApptResource","ResourceInClinicID":null,"ResourceInClinicName":null,"ResourceID":"d322a490-60ba-4739-a4ce-7d1de52f1789","ResourceName":"Dr. Maity","ResourceType":"Staff","ResourceRoster":[],"ResourceNotAvailableFrom":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceNotAvailableTo":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceSortedOrder":5,"ResourceKey":"Staff:d322a490-60ba-4739-a4ce-7d1de52f1789"},{"__type":"BusinessLayer.DTOApptResource","ResourceInClinicID":null,"ResourceInClinicName":null,"ResourceID":"e7217073-0763-4c42-8da0-7b4ce81f886a","ResourceName":"Dr. Shome","ResourceType":"Staff","ResourceRoster":[],"ResourceNotAvailableFrom":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceNotAvailableTo":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceSortedOrder":1,"ResourceKey":"Staff:e7217073-0763-4c42-8da0-7b4ce81f886a"},{"__type":"BusinessLayer.DTOApptResource","ResourceInClinicID":null,"ResourceInClinicName":null,"ResourceID":"670a9ec7-7502-4710-91d3-1c0dbe3023be","ResourceName":"TEST NEW DSHOME","ResourceType":"Staff","ResourceRoster":[],"ResourceNotAvailableFrom":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceNotAvailableTo":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceSortedOrder":2,"ResourceKey":"Staff:670a9ec7-7502-4710-91d3-1c0dbe3023be"},{"__type":"BusinessLayer.DTOApptResource","ResourceInClinicID":null,"ResourceInClinicName":null,"ResourceID":null,"ResourceName":null,"ResourceType":null,"ResourceRoster":null,"ResourceNotAvailableFrom":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceNotAvailableTo":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceSortedOrder":null,"ResourceKey":":"},{"__type":"BusinessLayer.DTOApptResource","ResourceInClinicID":null,"ResourceInClinicName":null,"ResourceID":"","ResourceName":"Hair care","ResourceType":"NonStaff","ResourceRoster":null,"ResourceNotAvailableFrom":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceNotAvailableTo":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceSortedOrder":null,"ResourceKey":"NonStaff:Hair care"},{"__type":"BusinessLayer.DTOApptResource","ResourceInClinicID":null,"ResourceInClinicName":null,"ResourceID":"","ResourceName":"New appointment","ResourceType":"NonStaff","ResourceRoster":null,"ResourceNotAvailableFrom":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceNotAvailableTo":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceSortedOrder":0,"ResourceKey":"NonStaff:New appointment"},{"__type":"BusinessLayer.DTOApptResource","ResourceInClinicID":null,"ResourceInClinicName":null,"ResourceID":"","ResourceName":"100 SRVC","ResourceType":"NonStaff","ResourceRoster":null,"ResourceNotAvailableFrom":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceNotAvailableTo":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceSortedOrder":null,"ResourceKey":"NonStaff:100 SRVC"},{"__type":"BusinessLayer.DTOApptResource","ResourceInClinicID":null,"ResourceInClinicName":null,"ResourceID":"","ResourceName":"Dressing","ResourceType":"NonStaff","ResourceRoster":null,"ResourceNotAvailableFrom":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceNotAvailableTo":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceSortedOrder":null,"ResourceKey":"NonStaff:Dressing"},{"__type":"BusinessLayer.DTOApptResource","ResourceInClinicID":null,"ResourceInClinicName":null,"ResourceID":"","ResourceName":"Hair care","ResourceType":"NonStaff","ResourceRoster":null,"ResourceNotAvailableFrom":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceNotAvailableTo":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceSortedOrder":null,"ResourceKey":"NonStaff:Hair care"},{"__type":"BusinessLayer.DTOApptResource","ResourceInClinicID":null,"ResourceInClinicName":null,"ResourceID":"","ResourceName":"smoothening","ResourceType":"NonStaff","ResourceRoster":null,"ResourceNotAvailableFrom":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceNotAvailableTo":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","ResourceSortedOrder":null,"ResourceKey":"NonStaff:smoothening"}]"
```

Comment: Why don't you use `sort` function to do it ?

Comment: I don't know how to use it I have tried but not getting how to use it

Comment: I already post the image for json and how you want it,tell me will post it

Comment: Have added that

Comment: yes as I am only setting that is there any way that i can set it anything else as data which are checked in the list having sorted value rest are null

Comment: Actually the JSON is coming from somewhere else and the checked items with the data and key are stored in some string from where I am fetching it and comparing it and ordering it.So the null ones and not null ones are already ordered in some default way which I can manipulate but I can change the object in js

Comment: Someone just post an answer , you can set a default value to nulls , if you want them in the top list , set nulls to some small numbers, oterwise set them large numbers .

Comment: Actually I need to place them as it is set by the user if you noticed user set  Dr.Maity that data on 5th position and it is checked above it there are two unchecked data now according to my code Dr.maity get placed at 4th position and according to that answer it is going to 3rd position

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124263/discussion-between-tanmay-and-passion).

Answer (score 3):

`result` is the result.
`sort` function is not used .

```
var checked = [];
var unchecked = [];

lst.map(function(item){
    if(item.ResourceSortedOrder !== null){
        checked.push(item);
    }else{
        unchecked.push(item);
    }
});

var result = [];

checked.map(function(item){
    result[item.ResourceSortedOrder] = item;
});

var index = 0;

unchecked.map(function(item){   
    while(result[index]){
        index ++;
    }
    result[index] = item;   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code instead of for loop to sort "lst".

```
 lst.sort(function (a, b) {
    var a1 = a.ResourceSortedOrder, b1 = b.ResourceSortedOrder;
    a1 = a1 == null ? 99999 : a1;
    b1 = b1 == null ? 99999 : b1;


    return a1 - b1 ;
});
```

Comment: Not working data Dr.Maity moving to two places up  now

Comment: I have tested results with your sample data. Dr matty have ResourceSortedOrder: 5. so its showing on 4th position. in 0,1,2,5 and so on.....

Comment: Yes but it should show on fifth postion and it is showing in 3rd position according to your code as list is starting from 0,thanks for helping if you get any solution please help me

Comment: Have you got default sort order. Suppose no item is checked then how will list be rearranged?

Comment: ya by default it is coming in some order but at that time resorcesorted object is nothing 0 it is getting value in client side only

Answer (score 0):

This code will place the item in list as specified in "ResourceSortedOrder".

```
var sortedList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
    var count = lst.length - sortedList.length;
    var item = null;
    for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        if (lst[j].ResourceSortedOrder == i) {
            item = lst[j];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (item != null) {
        sortedList.push(item);
    }
    else {
        sortedList.push(lst[i]);
    }
}
lst = sortedList;
```

Comment: thanks a lot buddy for help but it is not working the issue is because of null ones only...have to do something else by the way thanks

Comment: Best approach will be to save order of every item in a list. This is messing because order of item have null "ResourceSortedOrder" is unspecified

Comment: Also in sample json list there are some item having all values null, e.g ResourceName,  ResourceType, ResourceID